# Using an ANE with Flash CC

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, flash

I've used the command line to compile an AIR app with flash CS5.5 before. I was wondering if I would have to do the same with Flash CC because I've just recently upgraded to this version. Any help or feedback is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to use the command line with Flash CC.

A quick Google usually presents a solution.

Create a new project of the type AIR for iOS or AIR for Android. Click the wrench icon next to Script for ActionScript Settings button in the Publish pane. Select the Library Path tab. Click the Browse For Native Extension (ANE) File button and select the ANE file.